# How to create a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

i want a 1x16 dataframe (1 row, 16 columbs), but somehow R doesent allow me to define this

I can do it manually, but i am rather curious about what happens here:

```
  end.table <- data.frame(NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 16)
  names(end.table) <- c("last_obs", "mean6m", "sd6m", "zscore6m", 
                          "maxmin6m", "range6m",
                    "mean3m", "sd3m", "zscore3m", "maxmin3m", "range3m",
                    "mean1m", "sd1m", "zscore1m", "maxmin1m", "range1m")
```

it seems to me that my way of defining the end.table is wrong? How do you actually define a data.frame in R?

Comment: You probably need dimension names or a named matrix. Something like: `matrix(NA, 1, 16, dimnames = list(c("row"),
                                  c("last_obs", "mean6m", "sd6m", "zscore6m", 
                      "maxmin6m", "range6m",
                      "mean3m", "sd3m", "zscore3m", "maxmin3m", "range3m",
                      "mean1m", "sd1m", "zscore1m", "maxmin1m", "range1m")))`

Comment: Please study the documentation in `help("data.frame")`. You might find `help("matrix")` also relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Try these commands, directly in the console:

```
?data.frame
args(data.frame)
```

This will tell you how the function `data.frame` works. *Hint:* `data.frame` does not put any special meaning on neither `nrow` or `ncol` - that's `matrix`'s arguments.

A data.frame looks and feels like a matrix, but it's really a list-structure where each column is a vector with the restrictions that all columns must be the same length. The columns can each be of a different type, so the data frame can contain both text, numbers, logicals, etc. A matrix, on the other hand, is a 2 dimensional vector (column major) with the restriction that *all elements are the same type*.

To get your data.frame with least rewriting, I suggest you do this:

```
end.table <- matrix(NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 16)
colnames(end.table) <- c("last_obs", "mean6m", "sd6m", "zscore6m", 
                          "maxmin6m", "range6m",
                    "mean3m", "sd3m", "zscore3m", "maxmin3m", "range3m",
                    "mean1m", "sd1m", "zscore1m", "maxmin1m", "range1m")
# if you still need a data.frame and not a matrix,
as.data.frame(end.table)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
end.table <- data.frame(matrix(vector(mode = 'character',length = 16), nrow = 1, ncol = 16))
names(end.table) <- c("last_obs", "mean6m", "sd6m", "zscore6m", 
                          "maxmin6m", "range6m",
                    "mean3m", "sd3m", "zscore3m", "maxmin3m", "range3m",
                    "mean1m", "sd1m", "zscore1m", "maxmin1m", "range1m")
```